# Position of submatchings

Tags: python, regex

Let's consider the following code.

```
import re

text = "def oneFunc(x, y): return 0"

pattern = re.compile(
    r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"
)

print('---', text, sep = "\n")

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    mdict = m.groupdict()

    print('---', (m.start(), m.end()), sep = "\n")

    for name, textfound in mdict.items():
        if textfound != None:
            print((name, textfound))
```

This gives the following output.

```
---
def oneFunc(x, y): return 0
---
(0, 18)
('NAME_FUNC', 'oneFunc')
('DEF_FUNC', 'def oneFunc(x, y):')
---
(19, 25)
('OTHERS', 'return')
---
(26, 27)
('OTHERS', '0')
```

Is it possible to ask directly to `re` positions of submatchings ? For example, I would like to know that `'oneFunc'` begins at 4 and ends at 11, but I only have the positions of the biggest current matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start ?

So, `m.start('NAME_FUNC')` will return 4, etc. (same for `m.end(…)`, of course).

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry for my noisy question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, which is certainly correct, you might also find `.regs` and `.groups()` useful for something like this:

```
for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    group_indices = dict(zip(m.groups(), m.regs[1:]))  # the first element of m.regs is the overall match
```

The output is a `dict` that has the matched string/substring as key and the indices as the value. For example, the following three `dict`s would be the result of your searches above:

```
{'def oneFunc(x, y):': (0, 18), 'x, y': (12, 16), None: (-1, -1), 'oneFunc': (4, 11)}
{'return': (19, 25), None: (-1, -1)}
{None: (-1, -1), '0': (26, 27)}
```

You could, of course, also reverse the keys/values in these dictionaries by using `dict(zip(m.regs[1:], m.groups()))` instead of `dict(zip(m.groups(), m.regs[1:]))`.